# cabal install lens: library not found for -lHStransformers-compat-0.3.3.4-ghc7.8.3

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-lens

This is on Mac OS X with brew installed ghc and cabal-install. latest versions. ghc 7.8.3

When I run `cabal install lens` I get this error output:

```
Resolving dependencies...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/23/1yjxv_x14f1g817x9fz3wy500000gp/T/distributive-0.4.4-83867/distributive-0.4.4/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/23/1yjxv_x14f1g817x9fz3wy500000gp/T/distributive-0.4.4-83867/distributive-0.4.4/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/23/1yjxv_x14f1g817x9fz3wy500000gp/T/distributive-0.4.4-83867/distributive-0.4.4/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring distributive-0.4.4...
Building distributive-0.4.4...
Preprocessing library distributive-0.4.4...
[1 of 2] Compiling Data.Distributive.Generic ( src/Data/Distributive/Generic.hs, dist/build/Data/Distributive/Generic.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Data.Distributive ( src/Data/Distributive.hs, dist/build/Data/Distributive.o )
ld: library not found for -lHStransformers-compat-0.3.3.4-ghc7.8.3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Failed to install distributive-0.4.4
<snip>
Loading package primitive-0.5.3.0 ... <command line>: can't load .so/.DLL for: libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.dylib (dlopen(libHSprimitive-0.5.3.0.dylib, 9): image not found)
Failed to install vector-0.10.12.2
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
<snip>
```

`cabal -V` yields:

```
cabal-install version 1.20.0.3
using version 1.20.0.2 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: Do you have `transformers-compat` installed? Try running `cabal update && cabal install transformers-compat` first.
If you already have it installed, make sure that the library paths are in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: Works fine here from OSX Yosemite and a clean install.  Sorry :(

Comment: already did `cabal update` and I already have `transformers-compat` installed. I'm using OS X Yosemite as well.

Answer (score 0):

GHC 7.8.3 distributes `transformers-0.3.0.0` as a boot package, so you'll want to use these two packages:

```
transformers-0.3.0.0
transformers-compat-0.3.3.3
```

This this command when installing `lens`

```
cabal install --constraint=transformers\ installed lens
```

You can avoid replacing boot packages by adding global constraints to your `~/.cabal/config` file by adding this line to the end of that file.

```
constraint: transformers installed
```